# ASP.NET Fileupload and jquery .click

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, file-upload

I want to use a jquery button to use the fileupload asp.net component. This is my code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#choose").on("click", function () {

            $("#<%=upload.ClientID %>").click();

        });
        $("#<%=upload.ClientID %>").change(function () {
            var selectedFile = jQuery(this).val();
            var fileNameIndex = selectedFile.lastIndexOf("\\") + 1;
            var filename = selectedFile.substr(fileNameIndex);
            $("#filename").val(filename);

        });


    });
</script>
```

Where #choose is the jquery button #upload my asp:FileUpload component and #filename is an input text. Then I have another button (that we call "insert") that use the SaveAs() method of upload to save the file.

This is the aspx code:

```
    <asp:FileUpload ID="upload" runat="server"/>
    <a id="choose" >Choose file...</a>
    <input type="text" id="filename" value="No file selected" />
    <asp:Button ID="insert" runat="server" Text="Send" OnClick="insert_Click"
```

Clicking on jquery button fileupload open the window where I have to choose the file to upload and everything works fine on Chrome and Firefox.

Sadly on IE8 when I click on "insert" button doesn't fire any event and just empty the upload text. On the second click the insert button works, but the upload component is empty and throw exception because there is not a file to saveas().

Clicking on insert after clicking on #choose doesn't fire Page_Load as well. But if I click on insert before use #choose, it fires Page_Load. So, I think insert click after #choose click doesn't postback.

Comment: Did You used Update panels.....???....Post Some aspx code...